# How to get network data generated by Python + Selenium test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, browser-automation

Is there a way to get network data generated by Python 3.10 + Selenium 4.1.3 test?

I would like to examine network requests after the test has finished and Chrome instance is closed.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Reproducible example of what?

Comment: Of your particular issue, showing what have you tried until now.

Comment: Well I'm asking because I don't know what to do to get the logs.

Comment: Browsermob maybe. Playwright makes this a little easier

Answer (score 3):

For the latest `selenium`, getting network requests can be done via [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) and [selenium-wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire):

First, `pip install seleniumbase`, `pip install selenium-wire`, then run with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(wire=True)
driver.get("https://seleniumbase.io/demo_page")
for request in driver.requests:
    print(request.url)
driver.quit()
```

For the extended SeleniumBase APIs, there's this format:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(wire=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://seleniumbase.io/demo_page")
    for request in sb.driver.requests:
        print(request.url)
```

There's also a way that combines `seleniumbase` with `undetected-chromedriver` CDP Event capturing:

```py
import time
from pprint import pformat
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc_cdp_events=True)
driver.add_cdp_listener("*", lambda data: print(pformat(data)))
driver.get("https://seleniumbase.io/demo_page")
time.sleep(1)
driver.quit()
```

This one contains far more details in the output, but it's in a different format. Pick the option that works best for you.